# How to prevent component inside JScrollPane to resize?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a `JPanel` with a layout `CardLayout` and in every card there is another `JPanel` with a layout `BorderLayout` which has a `JScrollPane` inside.

ie.

```
JScrollPane jscrollPane = new JScrollPane(filter.getFilterComponent());
JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
jPanel.add(jscrollPane);

JPanel container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
container.add(jPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
```

`filter.getFilterComponent()` can be textbox, list of checkboxes or etc.

The problem is when it is a `JTextField` it look like this
[image: JTextField]

which is undesirable behavior. When I use `FlowLayout`, no matter how tall the component is the scroll bar doesn't appear. I think its because its parent container `preferredSize` is 0

**How can I prevent the component inside the `JScrollPane` from re sizing and keep its dimension to its original? Or there is another way of doing this?**

Comment: I'd try using a `GridBagLayout`, if that fails, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Alright i'll try `GridBagLayout` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `FlowLayout` instead of `BorderLayout`

```
JPanel container = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,0,0));
container.add(jPanel);
```

and set the preferred size of the `JScrollPane`

```
JScrollPane jscrollPane = new JScrollPane(filter.getFilterComponent());
jscrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(XX,YY));
```

`XX` and `YY` is the width and height of the parent container so if the content inside the scroll pane exceeds the preferred size, it will scroll

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)